# The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. Error when i call a service

Tags: iis, config

Hi i am calling a asmx web service in my MVC project. Everything working fine on my development environment but after publishing my project i get the error "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'". I tried a lot of methots on th internet bu they did'nt work. You can see my config down below and many thanks for help.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="FastApiSoap">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType=""/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="FastApiSoap12">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://fastsms.codec.com.tr/FastApi.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FastApiSoap"
        contract="SmsServices.FastApiSoap" name="FastApiSoap" />
      <endpoint address="http://fastsms.codec.com.tr/FastApi.asmx"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="FastApiSoap12"
        contract="SmsServices.FastApiSoap" name="FastApiSoap12" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solition. it was a bug, you can find fix on https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2801679/ssl-tls-communication-problems-after-you-install-kb-931125